# Disable third-party composer scripts when running through composer.phar?

Tags: php, mediawiki

We have a MediaWiki update procedure at [Website | mediawiki-install.txt](https://github.com/weidai11/website/blob/master/mediawiki/mediawiki-install.txt). MediaWiki requires the use of developer tools like Composer on a production server. It is a bad idea, but we cannot change it.

Step 7 requires us to run Composer and update dependencies.

```
php -d extension=phar.so composer.phar update
```

When the command executes it produces the following error:

```
# php -d extension=phar.so composer.phar update
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
> ComposerHookHandler::onPreUpdate
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
...
```

According to https://getcomposer.org/root, the fix is:

```
composer install --no-plugins --no-scripts ...
composer update --no-plugins --no-scripts ...
```

I tried to examine `composer.phar` to see what our options are but it is binary data:

```
# grep 'composer' composer.phar
Binary file composer.phar matches
# file composer.phar
composer.phar: data
```

My question is, how do we run `composer.phar` and ensure the source file does what is advised?

Answer (score 1):

Do not run Composer in production. Run it on a deploy host, and then depending on your level of paranoia either use rsync/ftp/scp/etc to upload the files to production, or commit them to a deploy repo which production can pull from after manual review.

Comment: Thanks Tgr. I tried that last year. We don't have a compatible image. I even tried to figure out a way to clone the remote image locally without success.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "image". Some kind of containerization? Composer doesn't really care about what OS it is running on.